# welcoming a chinese delegation

Tags: spoken

My girlfriend has to welcome and accompany a chinese delegation from different governmental institutions and companies, she wants to know if there are any common phrases for welcoming these guests in Mandarin Chinese.

Comment: 我们热烈欢迎代表团来访.... (dots needed for minimum length of comment)

Comment: 为了谦虚起见，第一人称代词＂我们＂也可以省略，就是说＂热烈欢迎代表团来访！＂也可以。（for the sake of modesty １。person personal pronoun 我们 might better be omitted）

Comment: girl friend at the end of her speech in some local language (German?) might pronounce the words: ＂热烈欢迎代表团来访！＂ after which the welcoming crowd might break into applause (confirming that they mean it and making the use of pronoun ＂we＂ 我们 unnecessary).
用地方语言（德语）的演讲结束时，女朋友可能宣称：＂热烈欢迎代表团来访！
接着欢迎群众中可以响起一片掌声证实他们的确是这个意思.

Answer (score 1):

I think it better to use "欢迎您的来访！", it does matter how many people are coming for visit. And can be reused for next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more Chinese style, say "热烈欢迎代表团莅临指导".